# A2DP/SCO -PCM/HCI

Tags: audio, bluetooth, codec

Wanted to know what exactly is the difference between routing the A2DP/SCO packets through PCM and HCI.

Do both PCM and HCI use ALSA framework for decoding the packets and then send it to speakers ?

Does PCM  require some special hardware and HCI does not ?

Comment: I might be wrong, but PCM usually stands for Pulse Code Modulation, which is a digital representation of an analogue signal, like sound; whereas HCI is a low-level interface in the Bluetooth protocol stack. So the two don't have much in common … other than that you might run across both when trying to understand Bluetooth stereo audio … PCM is a common uncompressed audio format, so it might make sense for a Bluetooth radio to accept PCM as input. To send it to a sink, it would use a codec, most likely the mandatory low-complexity and low-quality SBC, and not Atrac, MP3 or AAC.

Answer (score 3):

A paper, titled ["Audio Streaming over Bluetooth"](https://www.kernel.org/doc/ols/2008/ols2008v1-pages-193-196.pdf) (PDF) from the Ottowa Linux Summit 2008 may shed some more light on this.

In particular (quoting from page 194):

> The audio data transferred over the SCO channel can be
>   provided via the normal Host Controller Interface (HCI)
>   hardware driver or via a PCM back-channel. In case
>   of a desktop computer, the HCI will be used. In case
>   of an embedded device (for example a mobile phone),
>   the SCO channel will be directly connected via a PCM
>   interface to the main audio codec.

Answer (score 2):

A2DP uses ACL packets, voice calls (handsfree) uses SCO packets over the air.

HCI can transport both ACL and SCO, this is the case fx. when a BT dongle is plug'ed into a PC through USB. BT chips often have PCM interface to which SCO data can be routed but usually its not accessible unless you can access the PINs of the chip. The PCM interface can be connected to an analouge input/output.

Comment: I got interested in this Bluetooth audio business trying to understand why music was rendered in such poor quality over my Logitech Bluetooth Audio Adapter (audio sink, like headphones, just for plugging into an amplifier). Well, the answer is SBC, the mandatory codec in A2DP. If the audio sink accepted MP3 or AAC, and not just SBC, MP3 and AAC files could be sent over the air in compressed form, and decoded on arrival. Which would result in more efficient use of the bandwidth, and better sound quality. Instead, MP3 is decoded to PCM and then encoded to SBC (trashed), and then sent (as trash).